# nodejs tcp client-server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I am trying to get nodejs client-server with tcp working.  This is my code:

server.js containing the code for server

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});


console.log("Started Server");
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

client.js containing the code for client

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

when I run in 2 separate terminals node server.js , node client.js I get this error:

```
Started Server
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:546:26)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But if i Combine both of the codes together in a single process it works fine.  Anyone have any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: `client.on('data',` can fire many times while the data arrives, i really don't think you want to be killing it after the first chunk...

Comment: thanks dandavis it fixed my problem!